# Vue.js 2.0 Vee Validate plugin not clearing errors after ajax call

Tags: javascript, validation, vue.js, vuejs2

I am working on a vue.js 2.0 project. I am using the Vee-Validate plugin. I have a form and when it submits, it makes an ajax call to my api. After the api call returns successfully, I am trying to clear my vee-validation so that I can invite another user with the same form, but it's not working at all.

I tried the method this.errors.clear() as suggested in their  [documentation](http://vee-validate.logaretm.com/api#error-bag)

I have also thought that maybe its happening too fast, so I added a set timeout function for a couple seconds, but it still doesn't clear the errors.

Here is my Vue file with all related code:

```
    <template>
  <div v-if="user.first_time_login == 0 && user.stripe_check == 1">
    <div class="viv-modal-overlay">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="viv-modal green">
          <span class="modal-title" id="setup-team-top">Now let’s set up your team.</span>
          <p>Your plan allows up to {{this.user.company.max_users}} users. Would you like to shoot out some team invites before we send you to the dashboard?</p>
          <div class="invited-users" v-bind:class="{ show: show_invites }" v-if="show_invites">
            <p>You can invite up to 4 more team members. <a href="#">Upgrade to add more.</a></p>
            <ul>
              <li v-for="invite in invites">
                <img src="/img/icons/checkmark.svg" width="20" height="20" alt="success">
                You invited {{invite.email}}.
                <span class="clearfix"></span>
              </li>
            </ul>
            <div class="team-done-adding">
              <a href="#">I'm done adding team members.</a>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-form">
            <form id="setup-stripe-form">
              <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <label>Team Member's Email<span>*</span></label>
                    <input type="text" name="email" v-model="newUser.email" v-validate data-vv-rules="required" class="form-control" :placeholder="'user@'+user.company.company_name.replace(/[^A-Z0-9]+/ig, '').toLowerCase()+'.com'">
                    <span v-show="errors.has('email')" class="error">{{ errors.first('email') }}</span>
                  </div>
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <label>Access to Leads and Contacts<span>*</span></label>
                    <select name="access_leads" v-model="newUser.access_leads" v-validate data-vv-rules="required" class="form-control">
                      <option value="1">they can see leads and contacts they created</option>
                      <option value="2">they can see all leads and contacts</option>
                      <option value="0">no access to leads and contacts</option>
                    </select>
                    <span v-show="errors.has('access_leads')" class="error">{{ errors.first('access_leads') }}</span>
                  </div>
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <label>Access to Proposals<span>*</span></label>
                    <select name="access_proposals" v-model="newUser.access_proposals" v-validate data-vv-rules="required" class="form-control">
                      <option value="1">they can see proposals they created</option>
                      <option value="2">they can see all proposals</option>
                      <option value="0">no access to proposals</option>
                    </select>
                    <span v-show="errors.has('access_proposals')" class="error">{{ errors.first('access_proposals') }}</span>
                  </div>
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <label>Access to Invoices<span>*</span></label>
                    <select name="access_invoices" v-model="newUser.access_invoices" v-validate data-vv-rules="required" class="form-control">
                      <option value="1">they can see invoices they created</option>
                      <option value="2">they can see all invoices</option>
                      <option value="0">no access to invoices</option>
                    </select>
                    <span v-show="errors.has('access_invoices')" class="error">{{ errors.first('access_invoices') }}</span>
                  </div>
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <label>Access to Projects<span>*</span></label>
                    <select name="access_projects" v-model="newUser.access_projects" v-validate data-vv-rules="required" class="form-control">
                      <option value="1">they can see projects they created</option>
                      <option value="2">they can see all projects</option>
                      <option value="0">no access to projects</option>
                    </select>
                    <span v-show="errors.has('access_projects')" class="error">{{ errors.first('access_projects') }}</span>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-12 text-center">
                  <div class="modal-btn-pad">
                    <button type="submit" v-bind:class="{ disabled: adding_team_member }" class="btn btn-lg btn-green" @click="submitInviteForm">
                      <span class="sending-invite" v-if="adding_team_member">Sending Invite <img src="/img/preloader.svg" width="20" height="20"></span>
                      <span v-else>Continue</span>
                    </button><br>
                    <a class="light-link" href="#" @click="skipInviteForm">Skip this for now.</a>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </form>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import { mapState } from 'vuex'
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      newUser: {
        email: '',
        access_leads: 1,
        access_proposals: 1,
        access_invoices: 1,
        access_projects: 1
      },
      users_invited: 0,
      invites: [],
      show_invites: false,
      adding_team_member: false
    }
  },
  computed: mapState({
    appLoading: state => state.appLoading,
    user: state => state.user
  }),
  methods: {
    submitInviteForm: function(e) {

      e.preventDefault()

      this.$validator.validateAll()

      if (!this.errors.any()) {
        //There are no errors, move forward...

        //Add the team member to the database...

        //Grab the authorized user
        const authUser = JSON.parse(window.localStorage.getItem('authUser'))

        //Create the payload...
        var newTeamMember = this.newUser

        //Were adding a team member now so show the loader!
        this.adding_team_member = true

        //Create the new company and add the owner...
        this.$http.post('/api/team',
        {
          newTeamMember: JSON.stringify(newTeamMember)
        },
        {
          headers: {
            Authorization: 'Bearer ' + authUser.access_token
          }
        }).then((response) => {
          if(response.status === 200) {
            //Assign the user to a variable
            var invitedUser = response.body

            //Add the user to the list of invited users
            this.invites.push({email: invitedUser.email })

            //Show the invite list...
            this.show_invites = true

            //Jump to top
            location.hash = '#setup-team-top'

            //reset the new user
            this.newUser.email = ''
            this.newUser.access_leads = 1
            this.newUser.access_proposals = 1
            this.newUser.access_invoices = 1
            this.newUser.access_projects = 1

            //Were done adding a team member so hide the loader!
            this.adding_team_member = false

            //Clear the validation errors
            this.errors.clear()

          }
        }).catch(function(error){
            console.log(error);
        })

      }
    },
    skipInviteForm: function(e) {
      e.preventDefault()
      alert('skip invite!')
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

Answer (score -1):

Try to have a look at this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/zcppuzjc/5/) which was extracted from this [issue](https://github.com/baianat/vee-validate/issues/376).
Basically, you have to call `this.$validator.clean();` after you have reset the input fields of your form.